# How to disable form submit for all fields but the submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I disable form submit for all input fields but the submit button (with id called submit). The below code works but the problem is that I cannot do new lines in textareas. I am using jQuery. My goal is to prevent enter from submitting form.

```
$('form').on('keyup keypress', function(e) {
  var code;
  code = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if (code === 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check if the input textarea has focus or not.

check code snippet

```js
(function($) {
  $('form').on('keyup keypress', function(e) {
    if ($("input,textarea").is(":focus")) {
      //input and text area has focus
    } else {
      var code;
      code = e.keyCode || e.which;
      if (code === 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('hello');
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <textarea name="user_eingabe" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

*If there is no submit button, then pressing enter will never submit the form.*

Simply locate your submit button (either the input type="submit" or button) present and change your element to a type of button and assign a click handler to submit the form.

```
<input id="formSubmit" type="button" value="Submit" />
```

Don't forget, `<button>` implicitly has a type of submit, so if you use one, make sure that it is `type="button"` as well.

```
$("#formSubmit").click(function(){ $(this).closest("form").submit() });
```